# How does spellburn healing work with several ability scores

Tags: dungeon-crawl-classics-rpg

In DCC RPG, a Wizard may sacrifice some points of Strength, Agility or Stamina to give a one-time bonus on a spell check. These points of ability scores are not gone permanently, but can be healed.

> Ability scores lost in this way return as the wizard heals. Each day he does not attempt spellburn, he recovers **1 point of ability score.**

*(Emphasis mine.)*

My question is what does this "1 point of ability score mean"? One point in total, only increasing one of the three ability scores which it is possible to heal, or one point per ability score which has been depleted? I can't find any further clarification in the book.

Answer (score 2):

For my understanding, it is "one of the three ability scores which it is possible to heal". Is does not appear ambiguous for me, but English is not my mother tongue.
Anyway, this is simpler that way.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).